# Fluent паттерн с использованием методов с разными типами перегрузок

Tags: c#, функции, шаблоны-проектирования

Стоит задача сделать максимально простой и понятный интерфейс формирования некой логики. Я начал смотреть в сторону Fluent паттерна. И тут стал вопрос реализации, мне нужно добиться следующего примера составления логики:

```
LogicMaker.Create().AddRepoWithMethods(IEnumerable).Start(Enum).RepeatUntil(Func<bool>).CheckResult(Func<bool>).Start(Enum).RunCustomMethod(Action);
```

И тут появилась сложность, я не очень понимаю как организовать выполнение этой цепочки. Сделав эти методы расширения, я запускаю только первый метод, а как заставить всю цепочку выполняться не ясно. Нужны какие-нибудь примеры или статьи почитать, потому что в интернете я нашёл только простейшие примеры по формированию класса.

Comment: все просто: каждый из методов должен возвращать объект, у которого будет следующий вызываемый метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C# хорошим примером такого кода являются запросы в Linq.
Посмотри на объявления их методов в исходниках: [IQueryable.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs)
Например OrderBy. Он является расширением для IQueryable<> и возвращает IOrderedQueryable<> который является наследником IQueryable<>.

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
```

Благодаря этому ты можешь выстраивать цепочку вызовов различных методов.
Тебе нужно определить класс/интерфейс или набор класов/интерфейсов, над которыми будет выполняться твоя логика и каждый последующий метод должен возвращать один из этих типов/интерфейсов.

Например:

```
public class LogicMaker {

    public static LogicMaker AddRepoWithMethods(IEnumerable repoWithMethods){
        //Добавить repoWithMethods в this
        return this;
    }

    public static LogicMaker Start(Enum someEnum){
        //Сделать что-то с this
        return this;
    }
}
```

Если тебе нужно работать с разными типами, то тоже самое можно сделать в виде extensions.